# Projekt Hangman game

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and I am working right now with a small projekt, a hangman game. One of the functions I am working on right now is a `method` where it takes a `char` input, check if the input is already added to the `list` or not, if it is, a message will show up saying "You have already used that character!" and the user will have to guess again, otherwise the input will be added to the list. My issue right now is that nothing is happening, inputs are not added to the list at all.

This is what I have done so far:
Any advice/help would be appreciated!

```
public static ArrayList<Character> getGuesses(ArrayList<Character> allGuesses, char input){

        for (int i = 0; i < allGuesses.size(); i++) {
            if (allGuesses.get(i) == input) {
                System.out.println("You have already used that character!");
            }else {
                allGuesses.add(input);
            }
        }


    return allGuesses;

}
```

Comment: use more `System.out` logs to see what is really happening.

Comment: You can use [`ArrayList#contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) to get rid of that loop.

Comment: What is your question?  I assume it is not performing as expected.

Comment: And if you want to keep your loop: You need to move the adding of the new character outside of the loop and only do it when you are done checking your list and made sure that it isn't already part of the guesses. You currently add it every time when one of the elements in the list isn't equal to your new guess.

Comment: @maloomeister u are a legend, thank u!

Comment: @vsfDawg yes correct, the input is not added to the list wether its used or not. So my question is why nothing is happening? Why isnt the loop running?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thank u, I will try that right now!

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I tried your solution but the problem is that the loop is not going through the list at all bcs the list is empty in the beginning. Any suggestions when it comes to that?

Comment: Why is that a problem? That should make no difference. Just declare a `boolean alreadyUsed = false` before your loop, then in the loop when you find that the passed char already i part of the list you set that boolean to `true`. once the loop is done you check if `alreadyUsed == false` and only then add the new char. If the list is empty it doesn't matter because the logic described above would just work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the input character on each iteration as you search the collection.  You should only add it after you have searched the collection and not found it.

```
for (int index = 0 ; index < allGuesses.size() ; ++index) {
  if (allGuesses.get(index) == input) {
     System.out.println("You already used that character!");
     return allGuesses;
  }
}
allGuesses.add(input);
return allGuesses;
```

However, this can be simplified by using the Collection `contains` method such that you do not employ a loop.

```
if (allGuesses.contains(input)) {
  System.out.println("You already used that character!");
  return allGuesses;
}
allGuesses.add(input);
return allGuesses;
```

If possible, consider switching the type of `allGuesses` to a `Set` implementation  (e.g. `HashSet`).  A `Set` seems to better match how you are using your collection and allows you to reduce this method to...

```
if (! allGuesses.add(input)) {
  System.out.println("You already used that character!");
}
return allGuesses;
```